# Read and write a file with file chooser Android

Tags: java, android, file, read-write

i'm wiritng an app with Android Studio, I've setted a file chooser that give me the path of a file (the file could be on external or internal storage). I need read the chosen file, modify it and write in the same position with another name. I've implemented  read and write function but they don't work with separator because they use FileInputStream/FileOutputStream, i've tried already a function with FileReader but return null. Someone how resolve my problem?
Thanks in Advance!

My read/write function:

```
public String Read_file(String fn, Context context) {
    int ch;
    String d;
    StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(fn);
        try {
            while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
                fileContent.append((char)ch);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return d = new String(fileContent);
}


public void Write_file(String fn, String data, Context context){
    FileOutputStream outS;
    //Scrive sul file
    try {
        outS = context.openFileOutput(fn, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outS.write(data.getBytes());
        outS.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've already tried this but return null:

```
public String t(String fname){

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String response = null;

    try {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        //String fpath = "/sdcard/"+fname+".txt";

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line +"n");
        }
        response = output.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
    return response;
}
```

My choose file:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 10){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String src = uri.getPath();
            String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            String fn = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            System.out.println(fn);
            //////READ THE FILE AT THE URI
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I've setted a file chooser that give me the path of a file (the file could be on external or internal storage)" -- what exactly does this mean? Your code can read and write files from what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), but it will not work for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Also note that [you do not have access to most of external and removable storage on Android 10 and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Comment: With a file chooser i can select a file and return me the path (download folder or on sd card for example), but i need to read and write on that file

Comment: "With a file chooser i can select a file and return me the path" -- please edit your question and show the code where you are using this "file chooser". For example, if you mean `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, neither of those are "file" choosers, and with neither of those can you get a useful "path". So, while `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` are the right solution, you would need to use the `Uri` values as they are, with `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` and `openOutputStream()`.

Comment: yeah sorry, i've edited with my file chooser

Comment: That is an `onActivityResult()` method. If that is being called, it is because you are calling `startActivityForResult()` somewhere. What does that `startActivityForResult()` call use for its `Intent`? What is the `Intent` action? In general, a `Uri` is not a file. Calling `getPath()` on a `Uri` usually is pointless.

Comment: I think that the problem is the differences between content Uri and file Uri.. Can I convert it using RandomAccessFile?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue tring to open the file using fileName.getPath()
Kept getting file not found and all the content:path information was lost.
looking into content providers highlighted FileDescriptors.
Opening a fileDescriptor resulted in a ParcelFileDescriptor in which you can get the fileDescriptor and then onto opening a FileReader or an FileInputStream depending on your use case.

```
fun readFile(fileName: Uri): String? {
    val fileDescriptor = requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileName, "r") ?: return null
    val fReader = FileReader(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)

    //val file = File(fileName.path)
    var bufferedReader: BufferedReader? = null
    try {
        bufferedReader = BufferedReader(fReader)
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var line: String?
        while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line)
            stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator())
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        System.err.println("File :  Not found")
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            bufferedReader?.close()
            fReader.close()
            fileDescriptor.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return null
}
```